# What is the difference between LabelBinarizer and MultiLabelBinarizer?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am trying to understand the difference between the two label encoding techniques for output variable. I have read things but still can't get a clear picture as what makes them different. Also can we apply them on independent variables.

This is a project I am working on where I have to predict `Roles` for each observation. There are around 15k unique roles and each output variable has 3-20 combination of roles. This is where the binarizer comes into play.

Now when I do this

```
m=MultiLabelBinarizer()

ytrain=m.fit_transform(ytrain)
yval=m.transform(yval)
```

this is a warning I get **but I understand that these labels are not present in my training set also this would avoid leakage** but at the same time wouldn't this affect my model's performance.

```
'Senior Android Engineer', 'Senior Asset Manager', 'Senior Billing Manager', 'Senior Buyer', 'Senior Finance Analyst', 'Senior Manager Technical', 'Senior Nodejs Developer', 'Senior Optometrist', 'Senior Procurement Manager', 'Senior Revenue Assurance', 'Senior Visual Designer', 'Service Delivery Consultant', 'Shop Assistant', 'Site Deployment', 'Software Lead Tester', 'Solar Design Engineer', 'Sous Chef', 'Specialist Support Worker', 'Storage And Backup Engineer', 'Subject Matter Expert Data Science', 'Support Accountant', 'Support Engineer Information Technology', 'Sustainability Coordinator', 'System Support Specialist', 'Systems Developer', 'Team Lead Business Developer', 'Team Leader IT', 'Technical Operations Manager', 'Telecommunications Engineer', 'Telemetry Technician', 'Training and Competence Manager', 'Tutor', 'VP Production', 'Vice President Internal Audit', 'Vice President Investor Relations', 'Visual FoxPro Developer', 'Web Marketing Specialist', 'Web Producer', 'Welding Inspector', 'Work Life'] will be ignored
  warnings.warn('unknown class(es) {0} will be ignored'
```

So I would like to know if this is the correct way of using `MultiLabelBinarizer` or there is some other way to handle.

Any links, modules or answers is appreciated. Thankyou!!

Comment: One issue is that there are labels in the validation dataset that are not in the training set. The model can not make a prediction for those labels. A way to fix that is multi-label data stratification http://scikit.ml/stratification.html

Comment: @BrianSpiering even after using `iterative_train_test_split` i am getting this warning `Label not 2120 is present in all training examples.`

Answer (score 1):

Both are within one-vs-all scheme when there is a classification task.

`LabelBinarizer` it turn every variable into binary within a matrix where that variable is indicated as a column. In other words, it will turn a list into a matrix, where the number of columns in the target matrix is exactly as many as unique value in the input set. If your input labels look like `[1, 4, 5]` the resulting matrix, is a 3 column matrix and each `1, 4, 5` are a column. then if your instances (observations) are either of 1,4,5, it is gonna be indicated (binary) whether that instance correspond to label 1 or 4 or 5.

you use `LabelBinarizer` to build regular classifier, for example to train a logistic regression and create the response variable you can use

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit_transform(['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'])
```

the output is

```
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

or if your feature column is ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

`MultiLabelBinarizer` - does the similar thing but when you have multiple lables. when do you have multiple labels ? for example when you are doing mu
multiple label classification. Say, you are building a classifier to predict tags for Questions on StackoverFlow. Your data looks like this

```
   qId              Tag
0   1                       c#
1   2                     python
2   2                 machine_learning
3   2                     pandas
4   2                      nlp
```

but you have to convert it in a format where you can do machine learning (one row per observation)

| qId | c# | python | machine_learning | pandas | nlp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

and you will use

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

question_tags = pd.read_csv("question_tags.csv")
print(question_tags.head())
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print(mlb.fit_transform(question_tags))
```

I hope this clear out the differences when it comes to the practice

**UPDATE on your case**

how do you parse your 15K unique role to get those 3 category or combination ? is it like, *seniority, department, role* ? if so, shouldn't you make it like

```
question_tags = [{'Senior', 'Android', 'Engineer'}, {'Senior', 'Asset', 'Manager'}, {'Senior', 'Billing', 'Manager'}]
```

and then pass it to the

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
res = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(question_tags), columns=mlb.classes_)
```

and you will end up with

[image]

which shows all three are senior, number 2 and 3 are managers and so on ?

**UPDATE 2**

if you don't have it parse and basically just need to encode each of 15K unique label, you go with binary. For example you have four observation where two of them are senior android engieers.

```
question_tags = ['Senior Android Engineer','Senior Android Engineer', 'Senior Asset Manager',  'Senior Billing Manager'] 
lb = LabelBinarizer()
pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(question_tags), columns = lb.classes_)
```

[image]

Comment: so should I fit `mlb` only on **(training set and only transform testing set)** or **fit it on (training and testing set)** both. @user702846

Comment: both have attribute of fit and transform means you can used them both for training and test. As they are both carrying LABEL - it means one uses them for RESPONSE VARIABLE or the OUTPUT - however, you can also use them to encode your X matrix but it depends on the case and how you would like to go about it.

Comment: @10sha25 you can add your case as an example in the question and say which one should you use - so I can add that part into the answer as well if you like ...

Comment: I have edited my question. @user702846

Comment: I can't do that since each observation may have all `'Senior Android Engineer', 'Senior Asset Manager', 'Senior Billing Manager', 'Senior Buyer', 'Senior Finance Analyst', 'Senior Manager Technical', 'Senior Nodejs` or just `'Senior Nodejs`. If I do the way you mentioned how can I retrieve colname `Android Engineer` as a whole term which predicting

Comment: @10sha25 I tried to make a guess and be smart - sorry if that was not what you were after - I added update 2 - if it still needs improvement let me know.

Comment: In the update2 why did you use labelbinarizer @user702846

Comment: @10sha25  because you don't have multiple labels per observation in you example ! being senior android dev. is just one label for that observation in other words for every row you have only one column and want to encode that one column. in update1, for every row you have three labels

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn's [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) converts input labels into binary labels, each example belongs to a single class or not.

Scikit-learn's [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)
converts input labels into multilabel labels, each example can belong to multiple classes.